# Google map inside container

Tags: css, google-maps

i'm having some issues with placing Google map inside my Container, its giving some issue loading when i place it into any of my containers, it will only work outside of all my containers :(

```
<section class="lookingfor">
      <ul class="clearfix">
        <li class="homeMap">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

looking for class:

```
section.lookingfor .skills div.text {font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; color:#666; font-size:14px; line-height:22px;}
section.lookingfor ul li.homeMap {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

Not sure if the first line affects :O

Clearfix:

```
.clearfix:after {    content: ".";    display: block;    height: 0;    clear: both;    visibility: hidden;    }
```

homeMap class:

```
section.lookingfor ul li.homeMap {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What's the issue? Also it looks like none of your elements define `position`, so full width/height will be based on the page itself instead of the `<section>`. This might not be what you want if your page has any other content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set

```
position:relative;
```

and use fixed height&width instead of % because % will give you 0 height.
"That's because the div tries to be a percentage of the size of the , but by default the has an indeterminate height."

will fix the issue. Thanks to those who viewed :)

Comment: fix height screws up the controls (zoom in/out, pan left/right/top/down)