# Align google maps with another div next to it

Tags: html, css, google-maps, alignment, flexbox

The idea is to achieve this, without fixed heights. Before the validation they are both divs like 600px, but I want the google maps div to grow as the contact form div does. I tried the display: flex thing but I dont know if I am doing something wrong.

[image]

Comment: Possible repeat question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209704/set-google-maps-container-div-width-and-height-100

Answer (score 0):

If you submit the underlying code to the problem we could check if you used the "flex property" right. For a generally really good explanation on that topic you can take a read at: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

The easiest way of archieving this however would be using a height property of 100% on both, while wrapping them inside a div.