# Set Google Maps container size equal to md-card-content width

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, angular-material

How can set a Google Maps div container size equal to md-card-content width?

I have the following code but it doesn't work.

```
<style> #map { width: 100%; height: 100%; } </style>

<md-card flex>
    <md-card-content>
        <div layout="column">
            <md-input-container flex="100">
            <!-- ... -->
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

I try these solutions ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209704/set-google-maps-container-div-width-and-height-100), [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics?hl=en-EN#Async)) but it doesn't work for me. I also tried 
What I'd want get is like this:

[image]

Comment: Try setting `display:block; position:relative`

Comment: You can set margin: 0 -20px -20px -20px; for #map set px as per your parent element padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use angular but I'd say it's because of height is not set on a parent container.
From the image you've posted it seems that you want squared map.
You can use the padding trick to maintain aspect ratio:

```css
.map-container {
  position: relative;
}

.map-container:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  padding-top: 100%;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: tomato; /* only for testing */
}
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<md-card flex>
    <md-card-content>
        <div layout="column">
            <md-input-container flex="100">input</md-input-container>
            <!-- ... -->
            <div class="map-container">
              <div id="map">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```