# Angular - Google is not defined?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

Hi I am trying to implement `google maps api` in `angular`. It was pretty simple in `angularjs` but I cant figure out whats not working. I have a simple app which is showing products along with their location. Upon clicking location the location does show on map. But to shop map I am using `google maps`. I have done quite much. But this error is keep coming.

```
google is not defined
```

**app.component.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';
declare var google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [ProductService]
})
export class AppComponent {

  //define an array of products
  products = [];

  //constructor func
  constructor(private _productService: ProductService) { }

  //after constructor func this func runs , in which we are
  // accessing the class function getproducts and objects products
  // through this.
  // => means callback in which we are dumping data in products
  //array
  ngOnInit() {
    this._productService.getProducts()
      .subscribe(products => { this.products = products[0].data; console.log(this.products); })

    var map;
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
      zoom: 8
    });

  }

}
```

**Index.html**

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Shopober</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxx" async defer>


  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <table id="products">
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>In Stock</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Image</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let product of products">
      <td>{{product.id}}</td>
      <td>{{product.product_name}}</td>
      <td>{{product.product_price}}</td>
      <td>{{product.product_stock}}</td>
      <td>
        <a>{{product.location[0].lat + ',' + product.location[0].lng}}</a>
      </td>
      <td>{{product.product_image}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to wait the view initialization before loading the google maps script. You can do it with the `AfterViewInit` hook, like this :

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component} from '@angular/core';
...
export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // Load google maps script after view init
    const DSLScript = document.createElement('script');
    DSLScript.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxx'; // replace by your API key
    DSLScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.body.appendChild(DSLScript);
    document.body.removeChild(DSLScript);
  }
```

Comment: You want me to make another ts file and write this code ? Or can i do this in my app.comp.ts

Comment: Add it in the component that contain the google maps code!

Comment: Cannot find name 'AfterViewInit'.

Comment: same error. I did it something like this export class Appcomponent implement AfterViewInit {  products = []; 
  constructor(private _productService: ProductService) { }
......
Your code
 }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158601/discussion-between-usman-iqbal-and-boulboulouboule).

Comment: Now the map is not showing although it does come in html I checked in inspect element

Comment: Does the map have css `height` and `width` properties ?

Comment: I figure out the problem the height is not being set but I specifically add the height in css which is #map{height: 100%} but its not working unless i make it in px

Comment: Yes, it's the normal behavior of google maps, you have to set a fixed height in px, or resize the container too. Check this thread fot that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209704/set-google-maps-container-div-width-and-height-100

Answer (score 2):

Removing the **async** and **defer** attributes worked for me, but not sure it's wise to do keeping performance aspect of the website in mind.

so your script tag should look like:

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxx">`

Answer (score 0):

Trying implementing -

```
import GoogleMaps from 'google-maps';
```

After importing google-maps use below code:

```
GoogleMaps.KEY = <your map api key>;
GoogleMaps.load((google) => {
  // place your code here
});
```

Comment: dont want to use any plugin. Please explain with respect to orignal maps api

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your components load before the google script. There is a great angular2+ plugin for google maps : https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps

Did you check it out ? It allows you to do all the common stuff with google maps, and avoid the common loading and other errors.

Comment: i know this plugin but i dont want to use it

Comment: I'm not sure if suggesting a plugin without some additional explanations is a good answering practice.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably true. I'll add some details, sorry !

Comment: NOT a great plugin - in my opinion. I have encountered numerous bugs. Rather use the "google-map" that is now built into angular.

Answer (score 0):

Other way similar @Boulboulouboule solution

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component} from '@angular/core';
...
export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.httpClient.jsonp('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxx', 
      'callback')
      .pipe(
         map(() => true),
         catchError(() => of(false)),
      );
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping the initialization inside a `setTimeout()` function like below:

```
ngOnInit(){
 setTimeout(()=> {
 // Put the logic here 


 }, 1000);
}
```