# How to solve ReferenceError: google is not defined in Angular without using scripts?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58264355/how-to-solve-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined-in-angular?noredirect=1#comment102896610_58264355) question on how to solve `ReferenceError: google is not defined`.
The most important part of the code is the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.someContentWithAddress$ = this.someServiceWithContent.someContentWithAddress$.pipe(
            tap(someContentWithAddress => {
                this.address = someContentWithAddress.address;
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.calculateAddress(this.address);
                }, 1000);
            })
        );
    }
```

I'm using `setTimeout()` to solve the error, but it seems to me that this approach is not a good one.

Also the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47199133/9696675) in the recommended [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198904/angular-google-is-not-defined) doesn't work for me (still getting the same  error). 
I also don't want to use scripts to solve the problem.

Is there another way (that hopefully also works) to solve it?

Comment: DSLScript is just a variable name

Comment: Yes your right. My bad. I meant without using a script. will edit my question

Comment: Have you tried the second answer of wrapping it in a setTimeout?

Comment: Are you looking for third party modules to use google maps? since you are not interested in using `scripts` based solution. Then give https://angular-maps.com/ a shot

Comment: @Dhananjaipai If you take a look at my original question (first link) then you will see that I'm trying to get rid of my `setTimeout()`. I thought the `setTimeout()` is not the right way to solve this. And that made me write the post in the first place. But I'm not really sure if it's a bad solution or not.

Comment: @KarthickManoharan I'm already using `agm`. Take a look at my first link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to the problem can be found [here](http://roufid.com/angular-uncaught-referenceerror-google-not-defined/).

After installing `@types/ggoglemaps` like this:

```
npm install --save @types/googlemaps
```

the `MapsAPILoader` must be passed through the constructor and the `load()` method of it has to be used in `ngOnInit()` instead `setTimeout()`.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    ...

    constructor(
        private readonly someServiceWithContent: SomeServiceWithContent
        private mapsApiLoader: MapsAPILoader) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.someContentWithAddress$ = this.someServiceWithContent.someContentWithAddress$.pipe(
            tap(someContentWithAddress => {
                this.address = someContentWithAddress.address;
                this.mapsApiLoader.load().then(() => {
                this.calculateAddress(this.address);
                });
            })
        );
    }

...

}
```