# Google Maps embed not showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, vuejs2

I'm trying to set up a dynamic map with Vue.js

I'm porting [this code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap) to vue.

I've pretty much simply copied to function to a method like this:

```
        generateHeatmap(){
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 13,
            center: {lat: 37.775, lng: -122.434},
            mapTypeId: 'satellite'
          });

          const heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: this.getPoints(),
            map: map
          });
      },
```

The problem is that when I generate the heatmap the map doesn't show up. I can see that the html code changes in the console, but the html doesn't render anything. What am I missing?

This is a live Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/430049/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS, you only specify that the #map is `width: 100%`, but you need to actually specify a width and height. Something like this would work:

```
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

Edit:

Based on the comments you could use 100% width and height, see [this question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209704/set-google-maps-container-div-width-and-height-100).

Comment: I think here you can see how use `width:100%` and `height:100%` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209704/set-google-maps-container-div-width-and-height-100