# Adding Map w/ dynamic data to Google Sites

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sites

### Background

I am trying to add a Google Map to a (new) Google Sites; the map will have multiple markers whose data will change over time based on a Google Sheet.

### Where I am

I have been able to add a map w/ static data directly to the site using the "Embed" option, but I need to use Google Scripts functionality for the dynamic markers.

### Problem

When using the same html script and integrating it with Google Scripts, the text will show up on the Google Sites but not the map.

### Code

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Add Map</title>

    <style type="text/css">
      #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>

    <script>

      // Initialize and add the map
      function initMap() {
        // The location of Uluru
        const uluru = { lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036 };
        // The map, centered at Uluru
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru,
        });
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <!--The div element for the map -->
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
    <script async
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<API_KEY>&callback=initMap"
    >
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The API_KEY is filled in in the code. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Duplicate of [Set Google Maps Container DIV width and height 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209704/set-google-maps-container-div-width-and-height-100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the height is being set to 0 pixels; the map is inheriting from the parent block element, which isn't specifying a size resulting in the height being assumed to be 0 pixels. This can either be fixed by specifying a height in pixels:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

or specify that the height should be 100% of the HTML body:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
```