# Why google map doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am working with google map reverse geocode and my map doesn't show in my website. I copy my sample code and its working, and when i will paste it in my website file(with templates) its not showing

this is the code

```
<div id="map" style="width:50%;height:100%;"></div>
```

this is my script

```
       <script>
            function initMap() {
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 17,
          center: {lat: 16.0130425, lng: 120.35724399999998}
        });
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', function() {
          geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
        });
      }
      function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
        var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
        var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
        var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
        geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            if (results[0]) {
              map.setZoom(17);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
              });
              infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            } else {
              window.alert('No results found');
            }
          } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
  </script>
```

I have my API in my header.php

but when i check in my "Inspect Element" the div map have a data that have in my sample code

Comment: give map element height in px - <div id="map" style="width:50%;height:100px;"></div>

Comment: Thankyou dude. You help me a lot. Can u explain why the percentage sign doesn't work in height?

Comment: Accept answer if it is useful

Comment: Duplicate of [Google Maps API map doesn't appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741150/google-maps-api-map-doesnt-appear) and dozens of other Q/A.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="map" style="width:50%;height:100px;"></div>
```

Change to height to px or give height to parent or use `cal`

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to auto. A percentage height on the root element is relative
>   to the initial containing block.

For more ref [check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)